# How to make mysql LIKE search for exactly single words only

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where description like %STRING%
```

The problem is: When I search for `JAVA`it returns me even the records with `JAVAscript`.
But, JAVA != JavaScript, right ? How can I work around it ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM mytable where description = $STRING
any problem with this one?
and if you append '%' with 'JAVA' word and used like to make the search, it will search all the records that have substring 'JAVA';

Comment: @krishnaaryal Checking for an exact match would miss the case of the exact word occurring inside a larger string, and using `'JAVA%'` would include undesired matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL's `LIKE` operator isn't really suitable to detect an exact single word inside a string.  But `REGEXP`, which supports regular expressions, can handle this.  Consider the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE description REGEXP '[[:<:]]Java[[:>:]]';
```

This corresponds to matching the pattern `\bJava\b`, i.e. the word `Java` by itself.

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you are trying to execute this query using Laravel, then `whereRaw` should come in handy:

```
$results = DB::table('mytable')
            ->whereRaw('description REGEXP ?', ['[[:<:]]Java[[:>:]]'])
            ->get();
```

Comment: I'm having trouble converting this to laravel. Is there a similar result with `regex` instead of `regexp` ? Or some other kind of workaround.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Use `whereRaw`.

Comment: Already tried that:  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320448/using-regexp-with-laravel-query-builder?noredirect=1#comment81592750_47320448