# Using REGEXP with Laravel query builder

Tags: sql, laravel, sqlite, laravel-query-builder

I have the following query:

```
$registros = Oportunidade::whereRaw("descricao REGEXP '[[:<:]]". $search ."[[:>:]]'")->get();
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: REGEXP (SQL: select * from "oportunidades" where descricao REGEXP '[[:<:]]java[[:>:]]')

Also tried:

```
$registros = Oportunidade::where("descricao", "REGEXP", "'[[:<:]]'" .$search . "'[[:>:]]'")->get();
```

But for some reason I'm receiving this:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: REGEXP (SQL: select * from "oportunidades" where "descricao" REGEXP '[[:<:]]'java'[[:>:]]')
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: REGEXP

Why am I getting this error and how could I fix it ? The query works perfect without laravel.

#### Why Doing this ?

I was using `like %value%`:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where description like %STRING%
```

The problem is: When I search for `JAVA` it returns me even the records with `JAVAscript`.
But, JAVA != JavaScript, right ? How can I work around it using `Laravel`?
The only way I found using pure Mysql was with `REGEXP`

Comment: Why are you using `REGEXP` over there. You can use regex and sql `LIKE ` key word to search database table.

Comment: @SagarGautam No, I cant. Imagine that you have a lot of records with descriptions, some descriptions talk about `java` others talk about `javascript`. If you use `like` all of these records would be returned. But they are not the same thing, right ? Could you provide me an example, please ?

Comment: I think it seems like some syntax error so that **REGEXP** is not recognized as a function over there.

Comment: Did you read the error message `REGEXP '[[:<:]]'java'[[:>:]]'` ... the escaping is all wrong.

Comment: Use `whereRaw('description REGEXP ?', ['[[:<:]]Java[[:>:]]'])`

Comment: What database (DMS) are you using? MySQL, SQLite?

Comment: @fubar i'm using SQLite. Sorry for not mention it in first place.